# Sequelize CLI : cannot read property 'replace' of undefined when migrating DB

Tags: node.js, foreign-keys, sequelize.js, associations, sequelize-cli

I am trying to migrate DB using `db:migrate` function, however I am getting the error printed:

> ERROR: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

I have referred to other solutions for this error on GitHub but none resolve the issue. I am using sequelize-cli to perform migration.

here is my model:

```
    'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Containers', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      userId: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          references: "Users",
          refereceKey: "id",
          onUpdate: "cascade",
          onDelete: "cascade",
      },
      type: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      detail: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      checkin: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      checkout: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Containers');
  }
};
```

I have tried to execute other models by deleting this and nothing seems to work. Please help me here!

**UPDATE**

I have figured out that this is caused due to relations that I am trying to add, so I moved all the relations for all the posts in one separate migration:

```
    'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return [
        queryInterface.addColumn("Containers", "userId", {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            references: "Users",
            referenceKey: "id",
            onUpdate: "cascade",
            onDelete: "cascade"
        }),

        queryInterface.addColumn("Containers", "parentContainer", {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            references: "Containers",
            referenceKey: "id",
            onUpdate: "cascade",
            onDelete: "cascade"
        }),

        queryInterface.addColumn("Entities", "containerId", {
              type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
              references: "Containers",
              referenceKey: "id",
              onUpdate: "cascade",
              onDelete: "cascade",
        }),

        queryInterface.addColumn("Posts", "userId", {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                references: "Users",
                referenceKey: "id",
                onUpdate: "cascade",
                onDelete: "cascade"
        }),

        queryInterface.addColumn("Posts", "containerId", {
              type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
              references: "Containers",
              referenceKey: "id",
              onUpdate: "cascade",
              onDelete: "cascade",
              nullable: true
        }),

        queryInterface.addColumn("Votes", "userId", {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                references: "Users",
                referenceKey: "id",
                onUpdate: "cascade",
                onDelete: "cascade"
        }),

        queryInterface.addColumn("Votes", "postId", {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                references: "Posts",
                referenceKey: "id",
                onUpdate: "cascade",
                onDelete: "cascade"
        }),

        queryInterface.addColumn("Comments", "userId", {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                references: "Users",
                referenceKey: "id",
                onUpdate: "cascade",
                onDelete: "cascade"
        }),

        queryInterface.addColumn("Comments", "postId", {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                references: "Posts",
                referenceKey: "id",
                onUpdate: "cascade",
                onDelete: "cascade"
        }),

        queryInterface.addColumn("Comments", "commentId", {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                references: "Comments",
                referenceKey: "id",
                onUpdate: "cascade",
                onDelete: "cascade"
        }),
    ]
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

  }
};
```

Now, all the tables are created BUT, the error persists for this migration.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had this same error.

Solution: I change

```
...

references: TABLE_NAME,
referenceKey: COLUMN_NAME

...
```

to

```
...

references: {
 model: TABLE_NAME,
 key: COLUMN_NAME

...
```

and it works

Comment: And do not confuse `references.model` with `references.table` from `queryInterface.addConstraint`. table option doesn't work with `queryInterface.createTable` and `queryInterface.addColumn` in Sequelize 6

Answer (score 0):

For me it was coming from my environment variables not being loaded while doing `npx sequelize-cli db:create`. When I managed to load it (with dot-env loading in my config.js file + [dot-env cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-cli) to be sure) it worked fine.

If you use an IDE, you can climb to the definition that is being undefined. Or just check the slack trace.

To me, it was that line :

```
at getCreateDatabaseQuery (D:\Code\restaurant_project\website_engine\back_end\node_modules\sequelize-cli\lib\commands\database.js:82:64)
```

Leading to that line in the script (ctrl+click on the slack trace to go to the file)

```
return 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ' + queryGenerator.quoteIdentifier(config.database)
```

`config.database` wasn't defineds, hence the error.