# Sequelize, error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

If I remove the local, *Facebook* and *Google* sections the migration runs fine.  *Sequelize Node.js*.

```js
'use strict'
var DataTypes = require('sequelize/lib/data-types')

module.exports = {
  up: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    queryInterface.createTable(
      'users', {
        id: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true
        },
        method: {
          type: DataTypes.ENUM('local', 'google', 'facebook')
        },
        local: {
          email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
          },
          password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
          }
        },
        google: {
          id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
          }
        },
        facebook: {
          id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
          }
        },
        createdAt: {
          type: Sequelize.DATE
        },
        updatedAt: {
          type: Sequelize.DATE
        }
      }, {
        engine: 'InnoDB', // default: 'InnoDB'
        charset: 'latin1', // default: null
        schema: 'public' // default: public, PostgreSQL only.
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Full Error:

> ```sh
> Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
> Using environment "development".
> (node:6530) [SEQUELIZE0006] DeprecationWarning: This database engine version is not supported, please update your database server. More information https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/ENGINE.md
> (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
> == 20200627033341-users: migrating =======
> (node:6530) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
>     at MySQLQueryGenerator.attributeToSQL (/Users/chabgood/projects/ReactJS/Auth/api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query-generator.js:364:44)
>     at MySQLQueryGenerator.attributesToSQL (/Users/chabgood/projects/ReactJS/Auth/api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query-generator.js:434:45)
>     at MySQLQueryInterface.createTable (/Users/chabgood/projects/ReactJS/Auth/api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:222:38)
>     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> (node:6530) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:6530) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
> ```

Comment: I have the same issue but have no clue what it is.

Comment: I found that post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756410/sequelize-cli-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined-when-migrating-db.
I think that the problem is the syntax. Here is the correct code view:
    `userId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: "Users",
    refereceKey: "id",
    onUpdate: "cascade",
    onDelete: "cascade",
    },`